# How can I pass args in bash that is calling a python script

Tags: bash, python

I have a bash that calls a python script with optional command line args as

`python my_python_script.py "$@"`

My python script uses `argparse` to parse args.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-m', '--max_num', type=int, default=-1, help='To be used only if ran in dry run mode')
parser.add_argument('--dry_run', action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

However, the problem with about is that it adds `max_num` arg only if `dry_run` arg is passed. How can I make it independent and both args can be passed irrespective of each other.

Comment: What does this have to do with the outer bash script? Bash doesn't know how any given script or program parses its arguments, and doesn't have any automation except that which you've written yourself – so if you want the bash script to add some option, then just add it to the script?

Comment: Thanks @grawity I added and it worked. I wanted to handle via bash or know if there was a way but you clarified it. Thanks:-)